# Column wise operation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
 Id  priority1 priority2 priority3
  1    true      true     true
  2    false     true     true
  3    false     false    false
```

I need to create a new dataframe, where if first priority is true (order of priority priority1, priority2, priority3), I need to make all other priorities as false. Looking for a dynamic solution where I can add lot more priority columns.

Expected output from the example above:

```
Id  priority1 priority2 priority3   new_priority1 new_priority2 new_priority3
1    true      true     true         true           false         false
2    false     true     true         false          true          false
3    false     false    true         false          false         true
```

Comment: @manojlds,I tried to use foldLeft and creates new columns, But didn't go well. Currently trying with pivot transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put all the priority columns in an array and convert it to contain a single true value using an `UDF`. Then to get the array values into their own columns, use a `foldLeft`. Using the example input:

```
val df = Seq((1, true, true, true), (2, false, true, true), (3, false, false, false))
  .toDF("Id", "priority1", "priority2", "priority3")
```

The `UDF` and it's usage:

```
val convertPriorities = udf((prios: Seq[Boolean]) => {
  val falseSeq = Seq.fill(prios.length)(false)
  prios.indexOf(true) match {
    case -1 => falseSeq
    case x => falseSeq.updated(x, true)
  }
})

val prioColumns = Seq("priority1", "priority2", "priority3")
val df2 = df.withColumn("priorities", convertPriorities(array(prioColumns.map(col(_)):_*)))
```

Note that a `prioColumns` variable is created to make the `foldLeft` easier.

```
val df3 = prioColumns.zipWithIndex
  .foldLeft(df2)((df, col) => df.withColumn("new_" + col._1, $"priorities"(col._2)))
  .drop("priorities")
```

This will give the following resulting dataframe:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Id|priority1|priority2|priority3|new_priority1|new_priority2|new_priority3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1|     true|     true|     true|         true|        false|        false|
|  2|    false|     true|     true|        false|         true|        false|
|  3|    false|    false|    false|        false|        false|        false|
+---+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Using this approach it should be very easy to extend to use more columns, the only change that needs to be done is to add the columns to the `prioColumns` variable. This could be done by getting all column name and applying a filter if (as in the example above) the columns have similar names.